# Live Filtering on Large Amounts of Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, razor

I am working with ASP.NET Web Pages and I have a page with an account number textbox. I want to provide live filtering on the account number. In other words, as users type into the textbox, I want them to see a list of account numbers that match what has been entered. I originally thought that an HTML datalist would be perfect for this, but then I found that there are almost 300,000 possible account numbers. Datalists become unusable with more than a few thousand values.

One possible solution could be to let the user type 3 numbers, then call off to a WCF service which would send back a list of matching account numbers to populate the datalist with. I am new to ASP.NET Web Pages, however, and am not sure how to pass control to a C# function once 3 characters have been entered so that the service can be called. Also, when the data comes back, I'm unclear how I would get the data back to the client.

Any preferable solutions, or help with my  potential solution, would be appreciated.

Comment: How much rows of data you want to display ? I don't know whether you are open to JavaScript based table filtering libraries , I can suggest you a one then .

Comment: I'm pretty open to whatever solutions are out there, but I don't want the data to display in a table. I just want something that works like a html datalist which gives users filtered suggestions as they type.

Answer (score 1):

SlickGrid is a very good option for filtering over large number of rows and displaying them .